# Heroku for a new rails application only gemfile edited failed "Build failed -- check your build logs"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, push

I'm creating a new rails app in order to use it for practicing adding a front-end theme to it and makes it work, so I created a new rails application (totally new app), after that I just edited the rails app gemfile to add all the gems I added for my older projects, after that I created a new heroku repo, and tried to push my new project to heroku, but It want work and it failed, here are my gemfile and my heroku logs knowing that I'm totally newbie

my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.5.1"

gem 'rails',        '5.1.4'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.4', '>= 4.4.3'
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.3'      #for admin dashboard
gem "paperclip", "~> 6.0.0"      #for uploading photos
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'   
gem 'country_select'
gem 'bcrypt',       '3.1.12'
gem 'faker',          '1.7.3'
gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.7.0'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.11.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri       #for checking and debugging the code
  gem 'awesome_print'                          #for awesome printing the results in the rails console
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.10.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

my heroku logs

```
 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
            Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.1
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Fetching rake 12.3.1
       Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
       Fetching minitest 5.10.3
       Installing rake 12.3.1
       Installing minitest 5.10.3
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
       Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
       Fetching builder 3.2.3
       Installing builder 3.2.3
       Fetching erubi 1.7.1
       Installing erubi 1.7.1
       Fetching mini_portile2 2.3.0
       Fetching crass 1.0.4
       Installing mini_portile2 2.3.0
       Installing crass 1.0.4
       Fetching rack 2.0.5
       Installing rack 2.0.5
       Fetching nio4r 2.3.1
       Installing nio4r 2.3.1 with native extensions
       Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.3
       Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.3
       Fetching mini_mime 1.0.0
       Installing mini_mime 1.0.0
       Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Fetching execjs 2.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Fetching method_source 0.9.0
       Installing method_source 0.9.0
       Fetching thor 0.20.0
       Fetching formtastic_i18n 0.6.0
       Installing formtastic_i18n 0.6.0
       Installing thor 0.20.0
       Fetching kaminari-core 1.1.1
       Installing kaminari-core 1.1.1
       Fetching arel 8.0.0
       Installing arel 8.0.0
       Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.3
       Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.3
       Fetching ffi 1.9.25
       Fetching bcrypt 3.1.12
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.12 with native extensions
       Installing ffi 1.9.25 with native extensions
       Using bundler 1.15.2
       Using json 2.1.0
       Fetching mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
       Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
       Fetching mimemagic 0.3.2
       Installing mimemagic 0.3.2
       Fetching climate_control 0.2.0
       Installing climate_control 0.2.0
       Fetching i18n_data 0.8.0
       Installing i18n_data 0.8.0
       Fetching sixarm_ruby_unaccent 1.2.0
       Installing sixarm_ruby_unaccent 1.2.0
       Fetching unicode_utils 1.4.0
       Installing unicode_utils 1.4.0
       Fetching orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Fetching multi_json 1.13.1
       Installing multi_json 1.13.1
       Fetching pg 0.18.4
       Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
       Fetching puma 3.9.1
       Installing puma 3.9.1 with native extensions
       Fetching tilt 2.0.8
       Installing tilt 2.0.8
       Fetching tzinfo 1.2.5
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.5
       Fetching i18n 0.9.5
       Installing i18n 0.9.5
       Fetching nokogiri 1.8.4
       Installing nokogiri 1.8.4 with native extensions
       Fetching websocket-driver 0.6.5
       Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 with native extensions
       Fetching mail 2.7.0
       Installing mail 2.7.0
       Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Fetching autoprefixer-rails 9.0.0
       Installing autoprefixer-rails 9.0.0
       Fetching uglifier 3.2.0
       Installing uglifier 3.2.0
       Fetching rack-test 1.0.0
       Installing rack-test 1.0.0
       Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
       Installing sprockets 3.7.2
       Fetching warden 1.2.7
       Installing warden 1.2.7
       Fetching mime-types 3.1
       Installing mime-types 3.1
       Fetching terrapin 0.6.0
       Installing terrapin 0.6.0
       Fetching sort_alphabetical 1.1.0
       Installing sort_alphabetical 1.1.0
       Fetching rb-inotify 0.9.10
       Installing rb-inotify 0.9.10
       Fetching activesupport 5.1.4
       Installing activesupport 5.1.4
       Fetching money 6.12.0
       Installing money 6.12.0
       Fetching faker 1.7.3
       Installing faker 1.7.3
       Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
       Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
       Fetching globalid 0.4.1
       Installing globalid 0.4.1
       Fetching arbre 1.1.1
       Installing arbre 1.1.1
       Fetching activemodel 5.1.4
       Installing activemodel 5.1.4
       Fetching jbuilder 2.7.0
       Installing jbuilder 2.7.0
       Fetching countries 2.1.4
       Installing countries 2.1.4
       Fetching sass 3.5.7
       Installing sass 3.5.7
       Fetching activejob 5.1.4
       Installing activejob 5.1.4
       Fetching activerecord 5.1.4
       Installing activerecord 5.1.4
       Fetching carrierwave 0.11.2
       Installing carrierwave 0.11.2
       Fetching paperclip 6.0.0
       Installing paperclip 6.0.0
       Fetching country_select 3.1.1
       Installing country_select 3.1.1
       Fetching bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
       Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
       Fetching kaminari-activerecord 1.1.1
       Installing kaminari-activerecord 1.1.1
       Fetching polyamorous 1.3.3
       Installing polyamorous 1.3.3
       Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Fetching loofah 2.2.2
       Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Installing loofah 2.2.2
       Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
       Fetching actionview 5.1.4
       Installing actionview 5.1.4
       Fetching actionpack 5.1.4
       Fetching kaminari-actionview 1.1.1
       Installing kaminari-actionview 1.1.1
       Installing actionpack 5.1.4
       Fetching kaminari 1.1.1
       Installing kaminari 1.1.1
       Fetching actionmailer 5.1.4
       Fetching railties 5.1.4
       Fetching actioncable 5.1.4
       Installing actionmailer 5.1.4
       Installing actioncable 5.1.4
       Installing railties 5.1.4
       Fetching formtastic 3.1.5
       Installing formtastic 3.1.5
       Fetching has_scope 0.7.2
       Installing has_scope 0.7.2
       Fetching ransack 1.8.8
       Installing ransack 1.8.8
       Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Fetching responders 2.4.0
       Fetching coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Fetching jquery-rails 4.3.1
       Installing coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Installing responders 2.4.0
       Fetching rails 5.1.4
       Installing jquery-rails 4.3.1
       Installing rails 5.1.4
       Fetching sass-rails 5.0.6
       Fetching inherited_resources 1.8.0
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.6
       Installing inherited_resources 1.8.0
       Fetching devise 4.4.3
       Installing devise 4.4.3
       Fetching activeadmin 1.3.0
       Installing activeadmin 1.3.0
       Bundle complete! 29 Gemfile dependencies, 90 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Post-install message from sass:

       Ruby Sass is deprecated and will be unmaintained as of 26 March 2019.

       * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
         primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install

       * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
         sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme

       * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
         http://sass.logdown.com/posts/7081811

       Post-install message from paperclip:
       ##################################################
       #  NOTE FOR UPGRADING FROM 4.3.0 OR EARLIER      #
       ##################################################

       Paperclip is now compatible with aws-sdk >= 2.0.0.

       If you are using S3 storage, aws-sdk >= 2.0.0 requires you to make a few small
       changes:

       * You must set the `s3_region`
       * If you are explicitly setting permissions anywhere, such as in an initializer,
         note that the format of the permissions changed from using an underscore to
         using a hyphen. For example, `:public_read` needs to be changed to
         `public-read`.

       For a walkthrough of upgrading from 4 to 5 and aws-sdk >= 2.0 you can watch
       http://rubythursday.com/episodes/ruby-snack-27-upgrade-paperclip-and-aws-sdk-in-prep-for-rails-5
       Bundle completed (38.06s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       The latest bundler is 1.16.3, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
       To update, run `gem install bundler`
-----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
       Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
       rake aborted!
       Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'turbolinks' with type 'application/javascript'
       Checked in these paths: 
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/app/assets/config
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/app/assets/images
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/app/assets/javascripts
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/app/assets/stylesheets
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activeadmin-1.3.0/app/assets/images
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activeadmin-1.3.0/app/assets/javascripts
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activeadmin-1.3.0/app/assets/stylesheets
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activeadmin-1.3.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activeadmin-1.3.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/formtastic-3.1.5/app/assets/stylesheets
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actioncable-5.1.4/lib/assets/compiled
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/assets/compiled
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/node_modules
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/javascripts
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/fonts
         /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/images
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:14
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:65:in `resolve!'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:399:in `resolve'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:207:in `process_require_directive'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:180:in `block in process_directives'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `each'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `process_directives'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:83:in `_call'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:68:in `call'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:200:in `dfs'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_66540dbef9a5c6fa97bf6a74441a919d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this lines says: 
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'turbolinks' with type 'application/javascript'.

turbolinks gem is missing in your gemfile, maybe including it in your gemfile solves the issue.